# Passing dynamic parameters with ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, sql, dynamic, parameter-passing, expandoobject

I have some function whose prototype looks kind of like this:
`public void doThings(string sql, dynamic dParams);`

It does some kind of SQL querying with those parameters. I didn't write it but I have to use it. It works fine when I do something like this:

```
doThings("select * from SomeTable where myval1=@v1 and myval2=@v2",
        new
        {
            v1 = new Dapper.DbString()
            {
                Value = "yay",
                IsAnsi = true,
                Length = 50
            },
            v2 = new Dapper.DbString()
            {
                Value = "really",
                IsAnsi = true,
                Length = 32
            }
        });
```

But not when I first put the dynamic params into an ExpandoObject:

```
dynamic dynParams = new ExpandoObject();
dynParams.v1 = new Dapper.DbString()
    {
        Value = "yay",
        IsAnsi = true,
        Length = 50
    }
doThings("query here", dynParams);
```

The query then returns no results. I don't want to call `doThings()` and write that `new` block ten times for ten different scenarios where I might want to query for `myval2` or `myval3` and so on. Is there some special way I should be passing the `ExpandoObject`, or some other way I should be doing this in general?

Answer (score 5):

Dapper doesn't support Expandos by default, but you can pass the expando to the constructor of a `Dictionary<string,object>` and then pass that as the dynamic argument.

Answer (score 4):

As @Michael B has mentioned, Dapper does not support Expandos as params.

If you need to build your parameters set on the fly,
according to this [article](http://www.etcoding.com/blog/2012/04/13/Dapper-and-DynamicParameters/), you can use `DynamicParameters`.

Thus, you can build a translator from `dynParams` to `DynamicParameters`, and it would look something like:

```
dynamic dynParams = new ExpandoObject();
dynParams.v1 = new Dapper.DbString()
{
    Value = "yay",
    IsAnsi = true,
    Length = 50
};

var parameters = new Dapper.DynamicParameters();

((ExpandoObject)dynParams).ToList().ForEach(kvp => parameters.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
```

It think it could be a nice feature.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `doThings` is using reflection to get needed values, when you write:

```
new { 
    v1 = 1,
    v2 = "foo"
}
```

you are creating type with two properties `v1` and `v2`, but when you are
using `ExpandoObject` your *doesn't* add any new properties to `ExpandoObject` (all its magic behavior is a compiler generated stuff).

If you want to use `doThing` with properties known at compile time, I understand that there is no
problem. When properties are known at runtime the only way I can think about is to generate required anonymous type at runtime using `Reflection.Emit`. Look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121568/Dynamic-Type-Using-Reflection-Emit) article.